# Consume Salesforce wsdl in BizTalk application

Tags: wsdl, salesforce, biztalk, biztalk-2013

We have a BizTalk application where we consume the salesforce wsdl to create a Quote everything is working the Login helper is also setup. Now we added new fields in to the Salesforce we need to generate a new wsdl and update the binding and mapping in Biztalk

[image]

I generated the new wsdl for the class AxQuoteWebService. This returns the xml with the URL https://xyz.my.salesforce.com/services/wsdl/class/AxQuoteWebService. Then I went in to the existing BizTalk application and trying to add the new binding by Consume WCF service, selected Metadata Exchange and gave the URL. Getting below error

[image]

I have not used webservices in BizTalk before please let me know what I am missing here

Comment: Is there a way to upload a WSDL file in biztalk? Go to the salesforce url and wait for the page to load and right click the content and click save as. Save with a name and .wsdl at the end.

Comment: As per my response on https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/20a3d834-ae88-4c69-8197-f7403aa2cf7b/consume-salesforce-wsdl-in-biztalk-application?forum=biztalkgeneral  you are getting a HTML page rather than the WSDL.  Have you tried browsing to the page and see what you get? Is that the first screen shot?  Then press the Generate WSDL button, does it go to a new page? Then that is the URL you want. Or download a file? Then use that.  Or just edit your schema and add the new elements.  No need to regenerate